# Solving the 1-D diffusion equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For the equation $$u_t = Du_x$$

where $D$ is a diffusion constant, we can define the system
$$u_x=v$$$$u_t=Dv_x$$

However, how does one solve for $v$? $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=v \iff {\partial u}=v{\partial x}$, but how do we integrate $v(x,t)$ then?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics Write $(\nabla_{\text{respective }x\text{ and }t}u)\cdot_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(-D,1\right)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You can solve this by the Method of characteristics

Assume $u(s)=u(x(s),t(s))$ and differentiate with respect to $s$ and use the chain rule:

$$\dfrac{du}{ds}=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\dfrac{dx}{ds}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\dfrac{dt}{ds}.$$

Compare the coefficients to get 3 ordinary differential equations:

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=0$, $\dfrac{dx}{ds}=-D$ and $\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$. Can you complete it from here?

Answer (score 1):

There is a contradiction in the wording of the question :

[image]

If we ignore the contradiction, the solution is easy to find thanks to various methods , for example with the method of characteristics :

$u_t-Du_x=0\quad\to\quad$ The characteristic equation is : $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{-D}=\frac{du}{0}$

From $Ddt+dx=0$ , a characteristic curve is : $Dt+x=c_1$

$ \begin{cases}u=F(c_1)\\du=0\end{cases}$ on the characteristic curve. Hense :
$$u(x,t)=F(Dt+x)\quad \text{any differentiable function} F$$